# Python pytz: non-existent time gets AmbiguousTimeError, not NonExistentTimeError

Tags: python, timezone, pytz

How can I tell if a local time is non-existent? I'm trying with pytz, but it throws an AmbiguousTimeError, not a NonExistentTimeError.

2013-3-31 02:30 will never happen in Copenhagen due to daylight savings time.

```
local_tz = timezone('Europe/Copenhagen')
try:
    non_e = local_tz.localize(datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 31, 2, 30), is_dst = None) 
except pytz.AmbiguousTimeError:
    print "AmbiguousTimeError"
```

It goes to the exception handler. I've tried:

```
 except pytz.NonExistentTimeError: #'module' object has no attribute 'NonExistentTimeError'
 except pytz.exceptions.NonExistentTimeError: #'module' object has no attribute 'exceptions'
```

The user supplies me with a date and time via a form. These are in local time and I need to see whether the dates and times are ok.

I'm using Django with `USE_TZ = True`, but I don't think that matters here.

Comment: What version of the `pytz` module is this? I actually do have the `NonExistentTimeError` exception.

Comment: version 2006p. What's yours?

Comment: I see from the other answer that my version is really old. I downloaded it two days ago here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pytz/ I'll look around for the newer one.

Comment: As listed in my answer: `2012d`. You are 6 years behind. :-P

Comment: The [documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#latest-versions) points to [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Upgrade your `pytz` package. This works for me in version `2012d` for example:

```
>>> import pytz, datetime
>>> pytz.__version__
'2012d'
>>> local_tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Copenhagen')
>>> local_tz.localize(datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 31, 2, 30), is_dst=None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pytz/tzinfo.py", line 327, in localize
    raise NonExistentTimeError(dt)
pytz.exceptions.NonExistentTimeError: 2013-03-31 02:30:00
```

Use `pip install -U pytz` or `easy_install -U pytz` to upgrade.

Comment: Mine is 2006. It's is really old. I downloaded it two days ago here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pytz/ That seemed like a place that would have the updated one. I'll look around for the newer one.

Comment: Download it from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz/ (the Python package index) instead.

Comment: Not sure this should  be the accepted answer. It may help for some, but my version is 2017.2 and I'm getting this on `pytz.exceptions.AmbiguousTimeError: 2015-11-01 01:10:07`

Comment: @shacker: but that **is** an ambiguous time. In November the clocks go *back* and `1:10:07` occurs **twice**. That timestamp does *exist*, but it exists both at summer time (DST=1) and at standard time (DST=0).